# Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu Studio

Tags: music, ubuntu-studio

Can anyone please explain what is the *kernel* modification/upgrade involved when perfoming an Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu Studio? I am trying to follow this instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu

But then I wondering if I can install JACK and do it all manually. 
Thanks

Comment: You might want to search for 'generic vs lowlatency kernel'. Quite a few Q&As here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lowlatency (or realtime) kernel can be installed on it's own in any Ubuntu version, but system will run better with additional configuration Ubuntu Studio has already included.

This tool will run a script to check and advise adjustments needed for best performance with low latency audio
https://github.com/raboof/realtimeconfigquickscan